# Multiple buttons that will change the one text field to the value of that button using the one function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, textfield

okay so i have 10 buttons that are displayed 0 through to 9. 
There is a text field below that will display " button 3 is clicked" or "button 0 is clicked" depending on what button has been clicked and so on. 
However i have to achieve this with one function so my code looks a little something like this.

```
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">0</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">1</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">2</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">3</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">4</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">5</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">6</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">7</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">8</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber()">9</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <input type="text" id="garlicBread1" size="50%">
```

Im not sure how to make function changeNumber()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
 <button onClick="changeNumber(0)">0</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(1)">1</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(2)">2</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(3)">3</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(4)">4</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(5)">5</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(6)">6</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(7)">7</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(8)">8</button>
        <button onClick="changeNumber(9)">9</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        <input type="text" id="garlicBread1" size="50%"> 

    <script>
    function changeNumber(val){
     document.getElementById("garlicBread1").value =
        val + "clicked";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this. You can pass the reference of the element to the event handler and later use that to get the `innerHTML`

```js
function changeNumber(elm) {
  document.getElementById('garlicBread1').value = 'button ' + elm.innerHTML + ' is clicked';
}
```

```html
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">0</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">1</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">2</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">3</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">4</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">5</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">6</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">7</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">8</button>
<button onClick="changeNumber(this)">9</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="garlicBread1" size="50%">
```

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use `querySelectorAll` and and attach event listener to the button instead of adding `onclick` to each & every button. Then use template literal to create the string and attach it to the value of the input

```js
let getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let txt = e.target.textContent
    document.getElementById('garlicBread1').value = `button ${txt} is clicked`
  })
})
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="garlicBread1" size="50%">
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this, ie eliminating as much duplication as possible.

Answer (score 1):

agree with dk, just use it like this

```
 <button onClick="changeNumber()">0</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(1)">1</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(2)">2</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(3)">3</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(4)">4</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(5)">5</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(6)">6</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(7)">7</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(8)">8</button>
    <button onClick="changeNumber(9)">9</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <input type="text" id="garlicBread1" size="50%">
```

and in your function

```
function changeNumber(number){
console.log(number);
}
```